# socket begin receive callback unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In the below code state is an object which has a property msgLength which is the total message length.The msgLength is the first four bytes of the message.
I am getting unexpected results in the state.msgLength propery when more than one message is received in "quick" succesion.When the state.msglength is not as expected
I get an error trying to receive. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

```
              StateObj state = (StateObj)ar.AsyncState;

            try
            {
                state.read += state.socket.EndReceive(ar);
                if (state.read == 0)
                {
                    state.socket.Close();
                    state.socket.Dispose();
                    state.socket = null;
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm ss") + " socket closed"); });
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm ss") + " socket closed"); });
                return;
            }
            if (state.read < 4)
            {
                //read again you dont have state,msglength
                state.socket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, state.read, 4 - state.read, 0, cbReceive, state);
            }
            else
            {
                state.msglength = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.dataBuffer, 0);
            }
            if (state.read < state.msglength)
            {
                //read again you dont have the complete message 
                //here is the error Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
                state.socket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, state.read, state.msglength - state.read, 0, cbReceive, state);
            }
            else
            {
            //process here
             if (state.read > state.msglength )
                {
                    state.read = state.read - state.msglength;
                }
                else
                {
                    state.read = 0;
                }
                state.socket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, 0, state.dataBuffer.Length, 0, cbReceive, state);
            }
```

Comment: It is really hard for us to do psychic debugging on asynchronous socket code. **You** will have to print or inspect all relevant variables before the line where you'll receive the error, which will cause you to get an "Oh, snap!"-moment and solve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that *state.socket.BeginReceive* is executed twice. 
Because when it is reading it's header, both *if (state.read < 4)* and *if (state.read < state.msglength)* are true. Return after the first *state.socket.BeginReceive(*.. could solve the issue.

```
if (state.read < 4)
        {
            //read again you dont have state,msglength
            state.socket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, state.read, 4 - state.read, 0, cbReceive, state);
           return;  //  <------
        }
        else
        {
            state.msglength = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.dataBuffer, 0);
        }
        if (state.read < state.msglength)
        {
            //read again you dont have the complete message 
            //here is the error Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
            state.socket.BeginReceive(state.dataBuffer, state.read, state.msglength - state.read, 0, cbReceive, state);
        }
        else
        {
           state.read = 0;
          //process correctly expected message
        }
```

I think I found another issue, If the messageLength specified within the message is only the size of the data. You should read *if (state.read < state.msglength+4)* Because the length header is included in your buffer.

I mostly split-up reading header/data. Like:  (PSEUDO)

```
byte[] header;
byte[] buffer;
int bytesRead;

public void ReadHeader()
{
    bytesNeeded = 4;
    bytesRead = 0;
    BeginReadHeader();
}

public void BeginReadHeader()
{
    BeginReceive(header, bytesRead, bytesNeeded-bytesRead, EndReadHeader);
}
public void EndReadHeader()
{
    int read = EndReceive();

    if(read == 0)
    {
        CloseSocket();
        return;
    }

    bytesRead += read;

    if(bytesRead == byteNeeded)
        ReadData();
    else
        BeginReadHeader();
}

public void ReadData()
{
    bytesNeeded = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0);
    bytesRead = 0;
    if(buffer.Length < bytesNeeded)
        buffer = new byte[bytesNeeded];

    BeginReadData();
}

public void BeginReadData()
{
    BeginReceive(buffer, bytesRead, bytesNeeded-bytesRead, EndReadData);
}

public void EndReadData()
{
    int read = EndReceive();

    if(read == 0)
    {
        CloseSocket();
    }

    bytesRead += read;

    if(bytesRead == byteNeeded)
    {
        HandleData();
    }
    else
        BeginReadData();
}

public void HandleData()
{
     // handle data in buffer. BinaryReader

     ReadHeader();
}
```

Comment: I think the `else` will also be hit if no full prefix has been received yet, `state.msglength` is `0` and any byte `read` will be > `0`.

Comment: He's first receiving the first 4 bytes for the data length.

Comment: Yes, but if no 4 bytes have been received yet, the message length will be unkown. Won't happen often though.

Comment: will be unknown the first time.. That's why the second packet goes wrong.

Comment: why will it be unknown??